# Javascript: write in particular cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have this cell in my table in my div:

```
<body>
    <div>
    <table id="TableName" width="auto">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                ...
                <th colspan="7" style="background-color: black; color: white; text-align: left;">
                    <div id="last_thursday" />
                </th>
            </tr>
```

and this code to write the value of the date for the last thursday in it.

```
$(document).ready(Main);

    function Main() {
        ConfigDate();        
    }


    function ConfigDate() {
        var currentTime = new Date();
        var dayofWeek = currentTime.getDay();

        var daysSinceThursday = (dayofWeek + 3) % 7
        var lastThursday = new Date(currentTime.GetDate() - daysSinceThursday);
        var dd = lastThursday.getDate();

        var mm = lastThursday.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = lastThursday.getFullYear();

        $("#last_thursday").text(yyyy + " / " + mm + " / " + dd);
    }
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here cause my code isn't writting at all in my cell?

Comment: `GetDate` should be `getDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Wed Jun 27 2012 14:14:28 GMT+0100 (BST) has no method 'GetDate'
```

when I run it. I belive the method is `getDate()` with a small `g` for get.

Javascript console is your friend. :)

Comment: wow now i feel silly, I'm in an environment where it is deployed withtout debugger right now! thanks

Comment: Haha, don't feel silly! Sometimes its silly things like that that you least expect, and so you never look for! Sounds like a horrible working environment!

Comment: Yeah, this works. Most of my mistakes are like this, it's okay Senick. :)

Comment: Apparently I have a debugger, I just didn't know I could get it in IE in this particular place! thanks F12

Answer (score 2):

The console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object (...) has no method 'GetDate'
```

use `getDate` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/6axfn/1/.